# Footer connected to header wordpress

Tags: css, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi I was designing my own custom built template for my bandsite. everything went well untill in noticed that my aside wont float next to my youtube player and that my footer sticks to my header (ignoring the wrapper). I spent the whole afternoon trying to debug this, but no results. I think I might have overlooked something stupid.

http://theup.nl/wordpress/

The css

```
/* html element 62.5% font-size for REM use */
html {
    font-size:62.5%;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    color: white;


}
p {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: justify;

}
h1 {
        background-color: #111111;
        line-height: 1.4em;
        font-size: 2em;
        padding: 0;
        padding-left: 1.5%;
        margin: 0;
        font-weight: 300;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: white;
}
h2{
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 400;
}
h2 a { 
    color: white;
}
/* clear */
.clear:before,
.clear:after {
    content:' ';
    display:table;
}

.clear:after {
    clear:both;
}
.clear {
    *zoom:1;
}
img {
    max-width:100%;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
a {
    color:#444;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
    color:black;
}
a:focus {
    outline:0;
}
a:hover,
a:active {
    outline:0;
}
input:focus {
    outline:0;
    border:1px solid #04A4CC;
}

/*------------------------------------*\
    STRUCTURE
\*------------------------------------*/

/* wrapper */
.wrapper {

    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;

}
/* header */
.header {
    background-color: #111111;
    width: 100%;
    height: 375px;

    overflow: hidden;

}
#headerwrap {
    height: 375px;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;

}
#parallax0 {
        background-image-size: 375px 800px;
    background: url(img/para01.png) 50% 0 repeat-y fixed; 
    border-spacing: 0;


}
#parallax1{
    background: url(img/para02.png) 50% 0 repeat-y fixed; 
    background-image-size: 375px 800px;
}
#parallax2{
    background: url(img/para03.png) 50% 0 repeat-y fixed; 
    background-image-size: 375px 800px;

}
#parablock {
    height: 375px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color:red;

}

nav ul
{
    z-index: 500;
float:right;
width:100%;
padding:0;
margin:0;
margin-top: 10px;
list-style-type:none;
display: block;
position: relative;
}
nav a
{
float:right;
width:10%;

text-decoration:none;
text-align: center;
color:white;
font-size: 1.5em;
text-transform: uppercase;
    border: solid 1px;
    border-color: transparent;

}
nav a:hover {


    color: white;   
    border: solid 1px;
    border-color: white;
}
nav li {

}

/* logo */
.logo {

    width: 435px;
    height: 375px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
    background-image: url("img/logo.png");
}
.logo-img {
    display: none;
}
.slogan {
    width: 705px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 180px;
    left: 35%;
}
.slogan h1 {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    font-weight: 400;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
        font-size: 4em;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
        background-color: transparent;
    letter-spacing: -1.5px;
    text-transform: none;

}
.slogan h1 span {
    color: #316b00;
    background-color: #111111;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.slogan h1  .at {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400;
}
/* nav */
.nav {


}
/* sidebar */
.sidebar {
        width: 31.5%;
        float: right;
        background-color:  #316b00;
}
/* footer */
.footer {
    background-color: #111111;
    height: 100px;
    padding-top: 50px;

}
.post {

    width: 64.5%;
    background-color: #6b0021;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 2.5%;
}
.post01 {
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-right: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;

}
.youtubeplayer {

}
```

The html
Header

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

    <!-- wrapper -->


        <!-- header -->

        <header class="header" role="banner">
        <section id="parallax0" data-speed="0.7" data-type="background">
        <section id="parallax1" data-speed="0.8" data-type="background">
        <section id="parallax2" data-speed="0.9" data-type="background">

            <div id="headerwrap">
                    <nav class="nav" role="navigation">
                        <?php html5blank_nav(); ?>
                    </nav>
                    <!-- logo -->
                    <div class="logo">
                        <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
                            <!-- svg logo - toddmotto.com/mastering-svg-use-for-a-retina-web-fallbacks-with-png-script -->
                            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo-img">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slogan">
                        <h1> "Een uptempo band met een heel hoog<br> aaibaarheidsgehalte <span>en toch ook vette rock 'n roll.</span><span class="at">"</span></h1>
                    </div>
            </div>
                <!-- /logo -->

                <!-- nav -->

                <!-- /nav -->

        </section>
        </section>
        </section>
        </header>
<div class="wrapper">



        <!-- /header -->
```

index

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <section class="youtubeplayer post">
    <h1>Video</h1>
        <iframe width="100%" height="400" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Iv2SXP5VwAk?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </section>
    <!-- section -->
    <section class="post" role="main">

        <h1><?php _e( 'Latest Posts', 'html5blank' ); ?></h1>

        <?php get_template_part('loop'); ?>

        <?php get_template_part('pagination'); ?>

    </section>
    <!-- /section -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Sidebar

```
<!-- sidebar -->
<aside class="sidebar" role="complementary">

    <?php get_template_part('searchform'); ?>

    <div class="sidebar-widget">
        <?php if(!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('widget-area-1')) ?>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar-widget">
        <?php if(!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('widget-area-2')) ?>
    </div>

</aside>
<!-- /sidebar -->
```

footer

```
        <!-- footer -->
            </div>
        <footer class="footer" role="contentinfo">

            <!-- copyright -->
            <p class="copyright">
                &copy; <?php echo date("Y"); ?> Copyright <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>.  

            </p>
            <!-- /copyright -->

        </footer>
        <!-- /footer -->


    <!-- /wrapper -->

    <?php wp_footer(); ?>

    <!-- analytics -->
    <script>
        var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-XXXXXXXX-XX'],['_trackPageview']];
        (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
        g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)})(document,'script');
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: hi....please post your bug code here...

Comment: Your `<div class="wrapper">` doesn't get closed. I count 4x `<div>`, 3x `</div>` and there's a `</footer>` but no `<footer>`

Comment: @Marcel i messed up copying the code properly. sorry for that, the wrapper gets closed right before the footer

Comment: @Maxeerd Can you try adding `overflow:auto;` to `.wrapper`?

Comment: @Marcel somehow that did the trick.. can you explain what it did exactly and why it helped? Also, the aside still isnt floating next to the youtube which is weird

Comment: @Maxeerd I was adding a answer but I actually see no `<aside>` in the CSS or HTML, is it generated in the php?

Comment: @Marcel its loaded with  `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>`

Comment: try setting `float:right;` in `.sidebar` to `float:left;` (I don't see a `get_sidebar();` either.. ?)

Comment: @Marcel It should be visible now. The float left didn't do anything unfortunately

Comment: @Maxeerd posted possible answer : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No actual content (like `<p>`) results in the wrapper having no height, no height = non-existant. The content will show but any following element will ignore it's dimensions, breaking layouts. To have other elements respect the dimensions you'll have to set a manual height with `height: 300px;` or make it overflow with `overflow: auto;`

```
.wrapper {
   width:100%;
   margin:0 auto;
   padding-left: 10%;
   padding-right: 10%;
   overflow:auto;
}
```

To fix the location on this YouTube page, change the order of includes:
Set: `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>` after `<?php get_header(); ?>` instead of just before `get_footer();`.

Comment: You sir are the hero of the day! thank you very much! I would upvote, but I lack reputation (being new and stuff)